# update table using spring mvc web and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I have simple spring mvc web application which can handle simple book store. I have a problem when the existing book is updating.

I want to up date title of a book.
My updateBook.jsp is somethig like this.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Previous book title : <input type="text" name="previousTitle" /> <br>
    New book title :<input type="text" name="newTitle"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"/>
</form>
```

Problem: I have java class,"UpdateBookController" for handle the update of book. 
How can I handle the previous and new book titles in "UpdateBookController" class.

any idea..?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Spring 3.0 way

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository<Book, Integer> bookRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void updateTitle(@RequestParam("bookId") Integer bookId, 
                            @RequestParam("previousTitle") String previousTitle,
                            @RequestParam("newTitle") String newTitle) {

        Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId);
        book.setPreviousTitle(previousTitle);
        book.setNewTitle(newTitle);

        bookRepository.merge(book);
    }

}
```

Where BookRepository can be written as

```
@Repository
public class BookRepository extends AbstractRepository<Book, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void merge(Book book) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(book);
    }

}
```

If you want, you can create a custom UpdateTitleUseCase command class *which encapsulates previousTitle and newTitle attributes*. This way, your controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateTitle(UpdateTitleUseCase command) {
    Book book = bookRepository.findById(command.getBookId());
    book.setPreviousTitle(command.getPreviousTitle());
    book.setNewTitle(command.getNewTitle());

    bookRepository.merge(book);
}
```

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Thank you, Pascal. I am looking for your answers about unit-testing, testing and so on...

Comment: You'll find some answers but I didn't really post extensively on this topic (how went your talk by the way?). But my current toys include: [Arquillian](http://jboss.org/arquillian) (for integration or functional testing of Java EE 6), [Concordion](http://www.concordion.org/) for BDD.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Thank your for the links

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Session sess = null;
try {
  SessionFactory fact = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  sess = fact.openSession();
  Transaction tr = sess.beginTransaction();
  Book book = (Book)sess.get(Book.class, new Long(<id of the book to update>));
  book.setTitle(<new title>);
  sess.update(book);
  tr.commit();
  sess.close();
  System.out.println("Update successfully!");
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

However, you may want to use the DAO pattern to handle this in a neat way.

Comment: The whole point of using Spring is that you can skip all this boilerplate code. See here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight

Comment: Yes I know that, but originally there wasn't much specified in the question so I just gave a very basic overview of the steps involved to do an update. Of course you can use a transaction manager and stuff, but that's not the point of the question I believe...